# Why does the EUR symbol display for only some of the country bundles?

Tags: android, localization, internationalization

```
Currency euro = Currency.getInstance("EUR");
String ireland = euro.getSymbol(new Locale("en", "IE"));
String germany = euro.getSymbol(Locale.GERMANY);
```

The Value of ireland is: "¤"
The value of germany is: "€"

Germany is as expected, however the ireland one is not. So Why? I mean this is inconsistent with the rest of the behavior in the vm. I mean if I ask for a currency that I don't get a symbol for I usually get something like "EUR" as the symbol. What gives? I have to put a hack in my code for anywhere you get a "¤", then try to get another symbol as represented in another locale?

Does anyone know is such a country bundle should/shouldn't be installed or how to fix this?

Comment: "¤" is a placeholder which should be used when there is no country information. Seems like a bug.

Comment: yeah I find this on all versions of Android. It sounds like a huge oversite. One of those Locale bundle vs Context.getResources() issues I see in the SDK.